# Gitbash on Windows, where is my HISTFILE defined?

Tags: git-bash, bash

I am running gitbash on windows 8.  When I type env at the $ prompt one entry I see is 
HISTFILE=/i/.bash_history
where the i drive is my "personal" network drive at work.

I have no recollection of specifying this location when I installed git.

I can't find where this env variable is being stored so that I can go change it.  I don't seem to have a .bash_profile anywhere on my C drive or even on this i drive.

Where should I create a .bash_profile so I can control the location of this HISTFILE and also specify a size for history commands, which seems to be currently curtailed to 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the files like `.bashrc` and the `.bash_history` should be located under ~ (you user profile, so it will be somthing like `c:\users\<username>\.bashrc` for example)
so just run `cd` ir `cd ~` to get there and hen create the `.bashrc` with `touch .bashrc` and set your settings as normal.

Note that since this is a windows machine you don't have a `.bash_profile` since you don't logon to the machine into bash but rather start the terminal after logon. that's why you should use `.bashrc` instead